# How to make Generic method in C#

Tags: c#, web-services, generics

I have a lot of methods like these in a serviceContract I'm making:

```
   TemplateContract CreateTemplateContract(Template t)
    {
        return new TemplateContract()
        {
            Id = t.Id,
            Name = t.Name,
            Description = t.Description,
            DataLayoutId = t.DataLayoutId,
            FieldLayoutId = t.FieldLayoutId,
            SheetId = t.SheetId,
            ThemeId = t.ThemeId
        };
    }

    Template CreateTemplate(TemplateContract t)
    {
        return new Template()
        {
            Id = t.Id,
            Name = t.Name,
            Description = t.Description,
            DataLayoutId = t.DataLayoutId,
            FieldLayoutId = t.FieldLayoutId,
            SheetId = t.SheetId,
            ThemeId = t.ThemeId
        };
    }
```

These are methods to translate POCO's to DTO's and the other way around,
I was wondering if I could some of these generic, it would be a lot cleaner, but I haven't got a lot of experience in generic Coding and couldn't quiet figure it out yet

Comment: What exacly are you looking for? If you can give us some details, I might be able to help you out.

Comment: these 2 methods do the exact same code, they translate templateContract to Template and the other way around, so I would like to just use 1 method for this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You maybe better off looking at [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/) which can do a lot of this mapping automatically for you

if you really want to use generics unless they share a base class it's not possible, if they do you need to us a generic constraint on the base class and on a parameter less constructor so your method signature would be like

```
public TemplateBase Map< TemplateBase>(TemplateBase request) where TemplateBase : new
{
return new TemplateBase()
{
....
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/) that map in a very easy way?

If you don't want to use this library, you can at least watch the code to have inspiration.